# How to render a template by name?

Tags: servicestack

I am trying to get my head around ServiceStack **self-hosted** app and the new API.

Adding two views of the same name in separate folders results in an error at startup. Is this not allowed?

```
Foo\
  Index.cshtml

Bar\
  Index.cshtml
```

Is there a way to specify a template via a decorator on a method or directly as a return value? I know about the convention of naming views after DTOs. I prefer to be more explicit or follow a convention closer to Sinatra/Express.

```
return Render(typeof(Views.Foo.Index), new { Name = "Nelly" });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ServiceStack's [Razor Rockstars website](http://razor.servicestack.net) which holds the documentation for Razor support in ServiceStack lists some options for selecting a different template:

If it doesn't follow the convention (i.e. Request or Response DTO name) then you can dynamically specify which view or layout template gets used by returning a decorated `HttpResult` like:

```
return new HttpResult(dto) {
    View = {viewName},
    Template = {layoutName},
};
```

If you're using a static view (i.e. service always uses the same view) then you can specify what view to use by decorating it with the `[DefaultView]` attribute

```
[DefaultView("Rockstars")]
public object Get(Rockstars request) { 
    ...
    return responseDto; 
}
```

In either case, if you want it strong-typed you can use something like `typeof(RequestDto).Name`.

#### View names must be unique

Unlike MVC, heirachy's does not influence view selection in ServiceStack and because each **View Page** (i.e. razor pages in the `/Views` folder) must be unique, you're free to lay them out in any flat or nested folder structure you wish.